# Learning SSE/SSE2 and asm optimizations

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86, x86-64, sse

I'm familiar with C/C++ and assembly x86/x64 language, but now I need to study graphic optimizations (SSE/SSE2 and asm optimizations in general), what resources/books/links may I use to learn these topics? I've been searching across the web without much luck

Comment: More generally: http://www.agner.org/optimize/ lots of detail on how to optimize there. For a slightly more complete instruction latency table, see http://instlatx64.atw.hu/

Comment: Last semester I gave few lectures on CPU optimization, including SIMD,  and probably you will the lecture slides useful. http://www.cc.gatech.edu/grads/m/mdukhan3/

Comment: Just as a side note, messing with asm is usually a bad idea (at least if the reason is just optimization), especially for SSE. Use intrinsics, which are much easier to use, platform-independent (as platform-independent as you can get with SSE) and, even more important, more efficient, since the compiler is most probably much better at optimizing than you. Don't try to outsmart your compiler (or, if you want, then try *really hard*).

Comment: @ChristianRau really I would say that SSE is one of the best reasons - compilers barely optimize intrinsics code (the obvious things is about all), so you have to write it just right, and then hope&pray that the compiler doesn't make some stupid mistake in the register allocation (that has gotten better recently though). You then end up with code that is still optimized for a specific platform, and as a bonus it's harder to read than assembly, with all those spammy prefixes. The only benefit that I can see is that you can inline it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marco,

Three point response below :

1. If you want to learn a set of quick tricks, there are books available under general titles of algorithmic puzzles. The following two I have used and provide excellent challenge set to hone your skills. [Book1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321842685) is a collection of some very interesting tricks. I also enjoyed this [Book2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199740445).

Prof Agner's posts I think are the last word on the subject and they are a must read.

2. If you are seeking specifics of how to optimize, or use the 64 bit instruction set - my experience has been is to keep the Intel Manual Vol 2 handy. You may raise a specific question in this forum and get some excellent solutions. If you are seeking to start at a little more basic level, there is an excellent set of youtube tutorials by WhatsACreel - the coverage and explanations are superb. He takes you to AVX/AVX2 set over 60 odd sessions starting from basics.
3. I am not a professional programmer - I am a businesses management professional, but write 64 bit assembly language codes for academic institutions/folks whose PhD's are stuck or suffering/some such people in this ilk/ in my spare time. I think x64 is extremely powerful, beautifully compact, and does what no language can try and do. So, if anyone is trying to discourage you from writing in x64, citing complexity, or whatever else, please show them a disassembly of code generated by any compiler of their own choice :-) (should scare them enough) or, just gently ignore them.

All the best,

Comment: It is unusual to call University professors by their first names alone. What would professor Donald think about this?

Comment: On top of that it's unnecessary to be so formal except with Germans (then you have to use Herr Professor Doktor full name).